# SSIS Only Sparsely Populating SQL Server Column from CSV File that has a lot more data

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I'm running into a problem where I have a nvarchar(256) column in SQL Server.  I'm trying to populate it with data from a CSV file.  The CSV has a lot of data in this particular column.  I can open it up in Excel and see it.  I can use the "preview" functionality in the flat file connection manager in SSIS and see it.  Yet, in my data flow task, when I set up a data viewer path immediately out of the flat file source for the field, it is only showing about 120 out of the 962 fields as having any data.  I have the output column set up as DT_WSTR(256) in the source.

Is there anything I should verify I'm doing correctly?  What are my options in troubleshooting this?  I've looked at the values for that field in the raw CSV file that are not being inserted, and there doesn't appear to be anything unusual about them.

Comment: Are you sure all rows in CSV contain <256 characters? My guess is you may have set SSIS package to ignore the rows that exceeds this limit. Can you check that?

Comment: The largest size of any of the values is 71, and truncation errors are set to trigger a fail component.

Comment: It may be that number of columns is not the same in every row. Either by design or because of the incorrect delimiters. I would suggest to compare what you see in SSIS preview and what you see in Excel. Also try to change delimiters in flat connection manager to see if you can get different results.

Comment: We've now counted the tab occurrences before that field for records that are being pulled over successfully / unsuccessfully, and they had the same number.